# Mongoose.Find() with arrays and OR-operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to search a database rows that match a json object.

Example:

```js
var searchParams = {
    city: ['New York City', 'Budapest'], 
    jobs: ['Assistent'] //Can be multiple 
}

//If "city" is equal to one of the searchParams.city variables
//AND jobs is equal to one of the searchParams.jobs variables

var searchQuery = {
    $and: [
        {$or: clean_city},
        {$or: clean_cat}
    ]
}

Jobs.find(searchQuery, function(err, list){
    console.log(list);
});
```

I've tried all the options i could find on google but nothing seems to work with arrays.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help out.

Regards

Comment: What does your db object look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator) which makes, in your context, assuming:

- use of `searchParams` since I don't know what is in `clean_*` variables
- DB fields are `city` and `job`

```
{
  $and: [
    { $or: searchParams.city.map(city => ({ city })) },
    { $or: searchParams.jobs.map(job => ({ job })) }
  ]
}
```

Which is shorter syntax for (in case DB field names are different you can't shortcut it):

```
{
  $and: [
    { $or: searchParams.city.map((city) => { return { city: city }; }) },
    { $or: searchParams.city.map((job) => { return { job: job }; }) }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your objects in the mongo db look like this:

```
{
   "city": "New York City",
   "job": "Assistent"
}
```

You could do a query like:

```
Jobs.find({
   $and: [
      {
         city: { $in: ["NYC", "Paris"] }
      }, {
         job: { $in: ["Assistent"] }
      }
   ]
})
```

This will return any object which has a city among the city array, AND a job among the jobs array.